# Large Chart Copy Paste Excel VBA long time to perform

Tags: excel, vba, time, graph, charts

I have a large data set graphed (~970,000 points) and want to copy and paste into another sheet via VBA.  I have been successful but it is taking over 2 minutes to perform.  I am pasting as a picture.

Any thoughts/ideas on how I can do this in less time?  In another step, I want to copy the graph to a .ppt - I am currently copying the picture generated by the first step and pasting into .ppt in a short amount of time so the chart needs to be converted to a format - picture the best format?

Thanks (sry, having an issue uploading the few lines of code into the [Code] section that I'm currently using),

```
Sheets("hg Flow and Pressure").Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

With Worksheets("h For SinglePageExisting")        ' this takes over 2 minutes to process - tried
     .Activate                                      ' to make chart on anther worksheet - no luck
     .Range("T15").Select                           ' tried to change the formatting - no luck
     .Pictures.Paste.Select
 End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider plotting a smaller subset of the data, for example plot every tenth data point. Excel's graphs don't have particularly high resolution, so often there's little loss of detail when you remove a lot of points.

You can put a subset of data from column `A` in a helper column with a formula like:

```
=OFFSET($A$2,10*ROW()-48,0,1,1)
```

where `$A$2` is the start of the data, `10`, selects every 10th data point, and `-48` is an offset that depends on which row your helper column starts in. You can adjust the `10` and `-48` to match the details of your spreadsheet.

Hope that helps.

Comment: While this would indeed work, it's like giving up - maybe my only option but this is why I posted to the most experienced programmers in the world.  Was hoping there would be another way thru VBA, something like using the Snipping Tool - can this be programmed?

Comment: Maybe Excel's [camera tool](https://trumpexcel.com/excel-camera-tool/) would work.

Comment: Thanks, new tool to me, however it is limited to cells, doesn't work with graphs.  This is exactly inline with what I'm seeking.  Perhaps a similar tool exists?

Comment: If you embed your graph in a worksheet then the camera tool will capture it.

Answer (score 0):

Is "hg Flow and Pressure" the chart? It's on its own sheet? And "h For SinglePageExisting" is a worksheet?

So...

You don't need to go selecting and activating everything.

```
Charts("hg Flow and Pressure").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
Worksheets("h For SinglePageExisting").Paste
```